# Struts 2 - Pass hidden variable appended to URL on form submit

Tags: jsp, url, struts2, hidden

Can you please let me know how to pass a hidden variable appended on the URL when a submit a form.

Comment: I want to pass a hidden variable set it to true on submit and appended to the URL, when the user clicks on the URL the form wont be resubmitted. Please assist.

Comment: You can use url tag to build the url then add a hidden field as parameter.

Comment: Thanks Roman, I tried the below, but nothing is getting appended on the URL. Please help.                                                            <s:url id="test_url" action="update-incident" namespace="/portal/tickets" includeParams="none" escapeAmp="false">
 <s:param name="isSubmitted"  value="%{'false'}"/>
</s:url>

Answer (score 1):

Use struts tags.. see below example.

it contains **hyperlink example** and **hidden field example**

Put in jsp page

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>       
<s:form action="login" method="get">
    <s:url action="select-user" var="selecturl" >
        <s:param name="userid">1</s:param>
    </s:url>
    <s:a href="%{selecturl}" >Select</s:a>
    <s:hidden name="yourfield" value="1"></s:hidden>
    <s:submit />
</s:form>
```